# Domain name configuration issue

Tags: ssl-certificate, cpanel, domain-name

I had bought a domain name a couple mounths ago

when I type the domain name url on my navigator, it displays this message:

This domain is used just for tracking

I had linked the domain name to an ecommerce platform using dns1 and dns2, I still get the same message

but when I use a proxy everything is ok

I don't understand the problem

and should i buy a ssl certificate

I tried to use a proxy

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your domain showing ***This domain is used just for tracking*** likely stems from incomplete DNS propagation or incorrect DNS configuration.
Since the site works with a proxy, this indicates the DNS changes haven't been fully updated worldwide. Wait up to 48 hours for DNS propagation. Regarding an SSL certificate, it's highly recommended for an e-commerce site to secure customer data. Check if your e-commerce platform provides SSL, or consider purchasing one separately.
If issues persist after 48 hours, contact your ecommerce platform’s support for further assistance.